# How to get the bluetooth a2dp connetcted event on xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, bluetooth, a2dp

I have a xamarin project (API 28, soon to be 29), and I need to catch the event of bluetooth a2dp device.

I have a broadcast receiver with the following intent filter:

```
IntentFilter bluetoothFilter = new IntentFilter();
bluetoothFilter.AddAction(BluetoothDevice.ActionAclConnected);
bluetoothFilter.AddAction(BluetoothDevice.ActionAclDisconnectRequested);
bluetoothFilter.AddAction(BluetoothDevice.ActionAclDisconnected);
var btReciever = new BluetoothReceiver();
this.RegisterReceiver(btReciever, bluetoothFilter);
```

In my manisfest, I got the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

In the Receiver.OnReceive, I got this code:

```
public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.Action;
    BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice)intent.GetParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraDevice);
```

There I have a switch:

```
switch (action)
{
    case BluetoothDevice.ActionFound:
        Android.Util.Log.Debug(TAG, "Device Found");
        //Device found
        break;
    case BluetoothDevice.ActionAclConnected:
        Android.Util.Log.Debug(TAG, "Device Connected");

        BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter.GetProfileProxy(context, btsListener, ProfileType.A2dp);

        Thread.Sleep(1500);

        var manager = context.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService) as AudioManager;
        var devices = manager.GetDevices(GetDevicesTargets.Outputs);

        Android.Util.Log.Debug(TAG, "devices=" + devices.Length);
        foreach (var dev in devices)
        {
            Android.Util.Log.Debug(TAG, "dev: id={0} name={1} type={2}", dev.Id, dev.ProductName, dev.Type);
            if (dev.ProductName == device.Name)
            {

                 if (dev.Type.ToString().Contains("a2dp"))
                 {
                    BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter.GetProfileProxy(context, btsListener, ProfileType.A2dp);
                 }
                Android.Util.Log.Debug(TAG, "Found output device");
            }
         }
         //Device is now connected
         break;
         ...
}
```

And I got a listener that implements the IBluetoothProfileServiceListener interface, and looks like this:

```
var btsListener = new BTServiceListener();
class BTServiceListener : AppCompatActivity, IBluetoothProfileServiceListener
{
    public void OnServiceConnected([GeneratedEnum] ProfileType profile, IBluetoothProfile proxy)
    {
        if (profile == ProfileType.A2dp)
        {
            Android.Util.Log.Debug(TAG, "A2dp");
        }    
    }
    ...
}
```

I need to catch the event onConnect of the bluetooth a2dp (and later headset), but I have no idea how exactly I should do it.

This code in the receiver, shows the bluetooth onConnect event (BluetoothDevice.ActionAclConnected in the switch), then I check the device list, there is not yet the connected device, then I wait 1500ms (I need somehow to improve this method, this cannot stay like this), for the audioService to add the actual a2dp device to the list, and in the for loop, I find the additional device via its name, and I am certain it is the right one. BUT, I have no programmaticaly way to find out what type of device was connected (remote, headset, a2bp...) other than to check is the name contains a2dp (see for loop)

After my research, I found this line:

```
BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter.GetProfileProxy(context, btsListener, ProfileType.A2dp);
```

This uses the context, the listener, and the desierd type of device (see Listener: BTServiceListener ), the problem is, I don't know if the proxy in the listener is the same device as the device in the broadcast receiver onConnect, and I have no idea how to use that function.

So my questions:

1. How and when should I use the  BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter.GetProfileProxy function and be certain that I have the same device in the listener and in the onConnect function?
2. How to get all the devices from the manager without putting the thread to sleep? Because, without the Thread.Sleep, the actual device is not in the list because the onConnect function is called earlyer then the addition of the device to the audioService.

   Thread.Sleep(1500);  // <-- this needs to go

   var manager = context.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService) as AudioManager;
   var devices = manager.GetDevices(GetDevicesTargets.Outputs);
3. How should I distinguish between the device types? Because, I have a feeling that my method of String.Contains(string) is not the way to go

Sorry for the long question, thank you for your help and time.

Let me know, if you need anything else.

Comment: For the third question, please see my code https://github.com/851265601/Xamarin.Android_ListviewSelect/blob/master/Bluetooth.cs  In `GetHeadSetStatus` method. We can use ` ProfileState a2dp = ba.GetProfileConnectionState( ProfileType.xxx); ` to distinguish them. And monitor ble device‘s connection, please see `HeadsetPlugReceiver`.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Thank you very much, your code was very helpful, in fact it's the perfect workaround for me, it makes the first two questions redundant. The crutial part was to add the right intent action, I was specifying the IntentFilter for ANY bluetooth device, but your aproach specified the device, and it works perfect. Please post this here as an answer, so I can give you an upvote :) Also, I added the action into the switch, and the first time I do pair and connect it works, but if I only connect (already paired) then it wont catch it. Do you mby know why?